# Find array of all matches of sub expressions efficiently in perl

Tags: regex, perl

Suppose I have

```
my $xml = "<value>1</value><value>2</value><value>3</value> ... ";
```

I would like to extract the sequence 1,2,3, ... to an array `@values` as efficiently as possible.

I know I could loop over all matches and build up the array one at a time.
I also know that if I wanted an array with elements of the form `<value>i</value>` I could use

```
@values = $xml =~ m/<value>\d+?<\/value>/g;
```

Is there a similar line as the above to get just the numbers inbetween?

Comment: You almost certainly don't want to be parsing XML with a regex. Use an XML parser instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In list context, when a //g match has no captures, it returns what matched. If it has captures, it returns just the captured values.

```
my @values = $xml =~ m{<value>(\d+)</value>}g;
```

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if it would be more efficient to avoid the global pattern matching regular expression:

```
my @values = split /<\/values><value>/, $xml;
$values[0] ~= s/<value>//;
$values[-1] ~= s/<\/value>//;
```

---

```
use strict;             # Lets you know when you misspell variable names
use warnings;           # Warns of issues (using undefined variables
use feature qw(say);    # Let's you use 'say' instead of 'print' (No \n needed)
use Benchmark;
use autodie;            # Program automatically dies on bad file operations

my $string = "<value>1</value><value>2</value><value>3</value><value>4</value><value>5</value><value>6</value><value>7</value><value>8</value><value>9</value><value>10</value><value>11</value><value>12</value>";

my $ref =  timethese(1_000_000, {
    Regex => \&regex,
    Split => \&split,
}
);

sub regex {
    my @values = $string =~ m{<value>(\d+)</value>}g;
};

sub split {
    my @values = split /<\/value><value>/, $string;
    $values[0] =~ s/<value>//;
    $values[-1] =~ s/<\/values>//;
}

$ test.pl   
Benchmark: timing 1000000 iterations of Regex, Split...
Split:  4 wallclock secs ( 3.68 usr +  0.01 sys =  3.69 CPU) @ 271002.71/s (n=1000000)
Regex:  8 wallclock secs ( 6.99 usr +  0.02 sys =  7.01 CPU) @ 142653.35/s (n=1000000)
```

Comment: I don't know why you were downvoted for this. Thanks for taking a quantitative look and trying to actually solve the 'most efficient' part of my question.